# How do I check for the visibility of an element which may or may not be present?

Tags: java, selenium

Consider this url: https://sfbay.craigslist.org/pen/apa/5759740929.html
When you click the reply button, you will see a popup div with reply options. The div may or may not have phone numbers and a contact person name.

I made some code for this and I expect to work as mentioned in the points below.

1- If the reply button is clicked, then wait for reply options popup to be visible. When the popup is visible, then look for any phone numbers and extract them.

2- If no numbers are present on the popup, then do nothing (Its because the person does not want to share his/her phone number.)

3- If someone tries to extract phone numbers/names when the popup is not open, then throw a runtime exception which says that the reply button is not clicked.

Why does the code fail when I use wait_for_reply_options_popup_to_be_visible(), but passes when I use this:
wait_for_calling_options_to_be_visible();

Please help me to understand why and fix this issue. thanks !

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.List;

import static Utils.extract_phone_numbers;

public class Temp {
    private static final WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
    private static String url = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/pen/apa/5759740929.html";

    private WebElement reply_btn;
    private String reply_btn_xpath = "//button[contains(concat(\" \", normalize-space(@class), \" \"), \" "
            + "reply_button" + " \")]";
    private By reply_btn_loc = By.xpath(reply_btn_xpath);


    private String reply_options_xpath = "//button[contains(concat(\" \", normalize-space(@class), \" \"), \" "
            + "reply_options" + " \")]";
    private By reply_options_loc = By.xpath(reply_options_xpath);

    private String call_options_xpath = "//b[contains(text(), 'call') or contains(text(), 'text')]";
    private By call_options_loc = By.xpath(call_options_xpath);

    public String phone_xpath = "following-sibling::ul/li";
    public By phone_loc = By.xpath(phone_xpath);

    @Before
    public void before_each_test() {
        browser.get(url);
        load_elements();
    }

    @Test
    public void get_phone_number() throws Exception {
        reply_btn.click();
        List<String> phones = get_calling_or_texting_options();
        System.out.println(phones);
    }

    private void load_elements() {
        reply_btn = new WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(reply_btn_loc));
    }

    private void wait_for_calling_options_to_be_visible(){
        new WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(call_options_loc));
    }

    private void wait_for_reply_options_popup_to_be_visible(){
        new WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(reply_options_loc));
    }

    private List<String> get_calling_or_texting_options() {
        wait_for_reply_options_popup_to_be_visible();
        //wait_for_calling_options_to_be_visible();

        //Look for any element which contains call or text. Their sibling elements should have a number.
        List<WebElement> calling_options = browser.findElements(call_options_loc);
        WebElement calling_option = calling_options.get(0);

        if (calling_options.size() > 0) {
            //Get the sibling elements which contain phone numbers.
            WebElement phone_info = calling_option.findElement(phone_loc);

            //Remove all the extra text and extract only the phone number.
            List<String> phones = extract_phone_numbers(phone_info.getText());

            return phones;
        } else {
            String error = "Cannot get list of contact numbers! Please click the reply button first!";
            throw new RuntimeException(error);
        }

    }

}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //button[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " reply_options ")].......
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:261)
    at src.Temp.wait_for_reply_options_popup_to_be_visible(Temp.java:59)
    at src.Temp.get_calling_or_texting_options(Temp.java:63)
    at src.Temp.get_phone_number(Temp.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    .......
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html..........
............
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " reply_options ")]}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    ...........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebElement` objects will tell you if they are visible/enabled via a built in function.

```
try{
    if(someElement.isDisplayed()) {
        // Do something...
    } else {
        // Do nothing...
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do nothing or handle exception...
}
```

On a side note, it's usually better practice to have more...succinct names for functions for the sake of readability.  i.e. `wait_for_reply_options_popup_to_be_visible()` might be `waitForReplyOptions()`.

EDIT: Straight from the repo, it is suggested to make your own method to do this check, like the following:

```
public static boolean isPresentAndDisplayed(final WebElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: isDisplayed throws a NoSuchElementException instead of false when it is not displayed. Use a try catch instead

Comment: Updated with a try-catch.  Are you sure it always throws that exception on the equivalent of false?  Seems odd that they would design it like that.

Comment: @SusannahPotts - Which repo did you refer to ?

Comment: @SusannahPotts - Please tell me why one method in my code works, but the other fails. Btw, the "visibilityOf" methods which I used, actually invoke isDisplayed() just like your code. You can see that in the source code.

Comment: @testerjoe2 Sorry, give me a moment, I basically jump on while I wait for something to compile or I need a moment to breathe.  Here's the specific discussion I was reading: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1880

Comment: @testerjoe2 I'm not sure specifically why, it might be it needs a longer wait time, the xpath could be wrong, or the item just isn't visible.  Post a stacktrace and I can give you a better idea.  And I can't see that, or at least I don't see that, in your posted code.

Comment: Yes, the xpath is wrong. Forgot to change it when i copy pasta from the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method with try catch as above entry says. But I suggest not to use isDisplay() method itself. Instead you should made a method with using FluentWait()

```
public WebElement visibilityWait(int timeInMilliSeconds, By by) {
    WebElement element = null;
    try {
        element = new FluentWait<>(webDriver).
            withTimeout(timeoutInMilliSeconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            ignoring(NotFoundException.class).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class).
            until(visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        logger.warn("Ignore TimeoutException: ", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return element;
}
```

This methods return the element only if it's present and visible, if it's not returns null. You can give a timeout for your case, for example 15 seconds I don't know.

PS: Btw if one of your method is working and the other one is not, check your xpaths once again. Can't say anything more without seeing the website :)

Comment: The website can be seen by going to the url in the code.